# Putty SFTP client - "error while reading: failure"

Tags: batch-file, ftp, sftp, putty

I'm writing my sFTP files download command which run in the batch mode by using "mget *.txt", intermittently, there is "error while reading: failure" in my log, and this resulted the downloaded file is 0 KB, however i'm very sure that this file is exist in directory, as before downloading, im executing the "ls *.txt" command, and the log indicated the problematic file actually is not 0KB. I am looking for any auto recovery method or how could i solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you could try using rsync.  The [Grsync for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/grsync-win/) package includes rsync and a minimal amount of cygwin libraries to make it work.  Install that, add `c:\Program Files\Grsync\bin` to your path, and you can `rsync --progress --append user@remotehost:/path/to/*.txt localdest` to recover and resume your transfer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but looks complicated for me :) Just notice that i get this error when downloading the file #256, and this occur most of the time, and i think it's no coincident, guess there is some limit on number of files to be download to local when using mget.